# muliple index in heap table for on table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

For a table, do not have to use a lot of fields as the index, because the index volume is so high.

So, when need to run `sp` or `view`, Some fields may not exist in the index and return them have a lookup cast.

Now I use the cover index to prevent this problem and I want to create multiple indexes for each table, for every column in my sp does not exist in the index , either include (`cover index`)  add to index .

I might have to make 10 indexes for one table .

Do you think this is right now or not?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no simple answer. There's nothing inherently bad with having many indices on one table, and there's nothing inherently bad about using fields not part of an index. You need to decide on a case-by-case basis - is the cost of this particular index worth the savings? If possible, profile on real(istic) data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the benefit of having faster `SELECT`s with the overhead of having slower `INSERT`s, `DELETE`s, and `UPDATE`s - as in these cases the indexes need to be modified as well. As the above comment of Luaan says, there is no generally good or bad indexing, there are scenarios to choose from: what can you sacrifice for the benefit of something.
You also need to consider the maintenance of the indexes, because if there are modifications, there are fragmentations, and the benefit for `SELECT`s goes down.